# Referencing singleton body to singleton body without namespacing, but how?

Tags: javascript, object, singleton, return

My goal ist to reference a function into an singleton/object body!

#

This result is my goal:

```
var singletonObj_1 = (function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : function(){...},
               custom_fn2 : function(){...}    <<-- *But Imported
      }

})();
```

So after importing, i am able to call singletonObj_1.custom_fn2(); 
But custom_fn2 comes from another function-body, how to import it to look like above?

#

The second function "custom_fn2" is not declared in the upper function singletonObj_1!
It shall be imported, so that the result looks like above!

How singletonObj_1 acctually looks like:

```
var singletonObj_1 = (function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : function(){...},
               *Here I need any kind of reference to singletonObj_2.custom_fn1 to look like above
      }

})();


var singletonObj_2 = function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : function(){...} *This function shall be exported into singletonObj_1
      }

}
```

#

What i have tried without success:

```
var singletonObj_1 = (function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : function(){...},

               (function(){
                    singletonObj_2(); // just to return custom_fn1 : function(){...} 
                })();
      }

})();
```

Ofcourse i cant declare a self-invoking function within a singletonobject this way!
Hopefully i could express my problem!

Thanx alot in advance

sincerely yours
okyo

Comment: should singletonObj_1 and singletonObj_2 reside in different files, why you can't just put singletonObj_2 code into singletonObj_1? or they loaded via ajax or with some delay?

Answer (score 0):

```
var exported_fn = function () { ... };

var singletonObj_1 = (function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : function(){...},
               custom_fn2 : exported_fn
      };

})();


var singletonObj_2 = function () {
      return {
               custom_fn1 : exported_fn
      };
};
```